# AJAX IRCX Client and Server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, chat

I am currently developing an IRCX AJAX Chat Based system and have a few questions regarding the Server and Client implementation. Any suggestions are welcome:

**Server:**

Should this be implemented as a Web Service or a Windows Form application? I have experience in developing Windows forms based servers however I am wondering if this would be better implemented as a Web Service, if so why?

**Client:**

How are Web Based Clients implemented today and what is the preferred way to implement a web based client?

My solution so far are:

- ASP.NET Web Forms with an AJAX Update Panel (This seems the most viable)
- Using jQuery connecting to the web service with a JavaScript timeout

**Polling:**

How frequently should the server be polled for new messages?

0.5 seconds seems a bit excessive and anything between 2 or 3 seconds seems sluggish?

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently came accross this blog post from the **Trello** team: [The Trello Tech Stack](http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/)

This is not the only way to do it, but I have been very impressed by Trello and I'll certainly use it as an example of good practices for such applications.

The Stack Exchange chat is also impressive and I suggest you to read the blog of its [author](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha).

Comment: I would really like to stick with ASP.NET (Sockets) and the update panel, however I believe you answered the question of maintaining a persistent connection to the server (which jQuery wouldn't have provided)